# Autofill text box from dropdown list ERROR

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fill a textbox when a value is selected from a dropdown list.
I am able to do that, but in the process of doing so, I am unable to pick the value appearing in the textbox in my python script.

Now in my database I am getting a none value for the UserID. And the actual user ID is appearing in the Name column, as you can see in the screenshot.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 50px"><label for="form_lastname" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <select name="username" id="username" required class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="maahir10">Dadlani, Maahir</option> 
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="width:145px
    <label for="form_lastname" class="control-label">User ID</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="userid" style="height:35px;width:120px;font-family:Raleway" disabled="yes" required></textarea>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('userid');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('username');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
        mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

So, how do i fix this error and get both the values in my DB. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Are you not after `mytextbox.value` instead of `mytextbox.innerHTML`? (edit: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp)

Comment: Nope. I already tried that. It gives the same error. Thanks though.

Comment: Could the problem be you're not waiting for the window to load? Try wrapping the Javascript in `document.addEventListener('load', function () {` `Insert your code here` `});`

Comment: in your textarea you are using the disabled attribute, replace it with readonly, also you should use .value in your JS not .innerHTML because it's not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.value` option for input field not `.innerHTML`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('userid');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('username');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
        mytextbox.value = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

also you used disabled on your textarea, and that prevents the value to be sent via POST, use readonly instead.